# Java Regex to match supplied word with special charcters

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to match string by using Java Pattern class.

```
private boolean isMatch(String searchSentence, String matchWord) {
        String patternText = ".*\\b";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternText + matchWord + "\\b.*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchSentence);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

This will work if i have match string, which doesn't contains any special character like ({[ etc.

I am able to find **"RANCH"** but not **"RANCH (EAGLEFORD)"**.

Few more examples

1. Let say my input string is: **"Point [-99.73586,28.38092]"** then i should be able to search for **"-99.73586,28.38092"**
2. Let say my input string is: **"Point [-99.73586,28.38092]"** then i should be able to search for **"[-99.73586,28.38092]"**
3. Let say my input string is: **"Rench RenchY"** then i should be able to search for **"Rench"** but RenchY Should not be the part of search result.
   So how can i handle these type of case.

Comment: What is the sample input? what is the expected output?, what are you trying to do?

Comment: What is a word boundary for you? Is a "word" just a chunk of non-whitespace chars? Note the `)` is not a word char, the `\b` after it will require a word char right after the parenthesis. Another issue is that you need to use `Pattern.quote(matchWord)`.

Comment: Let's try to clarify it via a hint: try `Pattern.compile(".*(?<!\\S)" + Pattern.quote(matchWord) + "(?!\\S).*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

Answer (score 0):

Example of using special characters ({}) in regex

String stringToSearch = "Some lengthy string I am trying to RANCH (EAGLEFORD) and  RANCH {EAGLEFORD}";

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("RANCH\\s[(){}\\w]+");

Matcher m = p1.matcher(stringToSearch);

while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());   
}
```

output:

RANCH (EAGLEFORD)
RANCH {EAGLEFORD}

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to match your keywords not enclosed with *word* chars (letters, digits, or underscores), use `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` lookarounds instead of `\b`.

```
private boolean isMatch(String searchSentence, String matchWord) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)" + Pattern.quote(matchWord) + "(?!\\w)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchSentence);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

If you only plan to find matches enclosed with whitespace/start/end of string, use `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` lookarounds:

```
private boolean isMatch(String searchSentence, String matchWord) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)" + Pattern.quote(matchWord) + "(?!\\S)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchSentence);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Do not forget to `Pattern.quote` your literal strings.

Using `Matcher#find` is preferable since you do not need the initial/trailing `.*` and eliminates unnecessary overhead related to regex backtracking mechanism.